# Solr query with repeating parameter

Tags: solr, configuration, query-parser

I try to "extend" one of the examples from the Solr Query Parsing presentation ( http://www.slideshare.net/erikhatcher/sa-22830939 ). I'd like to extend it in a way that I'm able to retrieve multiple solr documents at once with a querystring which `http://.../solr/docs?id=1&id=2&id=3`

The original configuration for the requestHandler looks like this:

```
   <requestHandler name="/docs" class="solr.SearchHandler">
      <lst name="defaults">
        <str name="q">{!term f=id v=$id}</str>
      </lst>
      <arr name="components">
        <str>query</str>
        <str>highlight</str>
        <str>debug</str>
      </arr>
   </requestHandler>
```

But this works only for a single `id` parameter ( `http://.../solr/docs?id=1` ) - which query parser or configuration would I have to use to match it against multiple `id` parameters?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: will id=1|id=2|id=3 work ? I think your syntax is doing a boolean conjunction on different id's, which will match nothing: a==1 AND a==2

Comment: Parameter dereferencing will not pick up multiple parameter values, there is no syntax to define how those values should be combined/expanded into the single `v` value.